# Retrieving page content from Confluence REST with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, confluence-rest-api

I want to calculate word statistics on pages in my knowledge base that runs on Confluence.

But before I do the calculations, I'd like to retrieve page data: text written on the pages.

I have a Python script that was originally made to collect commentary from pages.
I am trying to adapt the script for /rest/api/content/{id} REST API that I have found with Confluence REST browser.

The original script uses API that returns result as a JSON object that when parsed with json() method returns dictionary objects.

However, the /rest/api/content/{id} API returns a result that does not contain a well formed dictionary. I receive string objects, and I cannot simply address them as array['index'] =  result ['value'] to retrieve page data.

I am using JupyterLab environment to run the code.

When using Confluecne Browser and /rest/api/content/{id} API for the page 4068365, Confluence returns the following result:

```
{
  "id": "4068365",
  "type": "page",
  "status": "current",
  "title": "Page title",
  "body": {
    "view": {
      "value": "<p>Some text</p>",
      "representation": "storage",
      "_expandable": {
        "webresource": "",
        "content": "/rest/api/content/4068365"
      }
    },
    "_expandable": {
      "editor": "",
      "export_view": "",
      "styled_view": "",
      "storage": "",
      "anonymous_export_view": ""
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "position": "none"
  },

...
```

I'd like to obtain the value of 'value' key. However, the 'value' param is not recognized as a key because the result is formatted as a string and not as a dictionary.

Here's the code I have.

```py
import requests
import json
import getpass
import re
import html
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Allow HTTPS connections with self-signed cert
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

# Create login session for Confluence
auth = ('mylogin', getpass.getpass())
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = auth
s.verify = False
s.headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

# Confluence REST API URI
WIKI = 'https://example.net/wiki/rest/api/'

# Obtain text from Confluence HTML layout
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    text = html.unescape(raw_html)
    text = re.sub(cleanr, '', text)
    text = text.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
    return text

# Retrieving page data
def get_data(page_id):
    data = []
    r = s.get(
     '{}content/{}'.format(WIKI, page_id),
      params = dict(
       expand='body.view'
       )      
    )
    for content in r.json():
        pgdata = dict()
#I can't address to value as content['value']
        pgdata['text'] = cleanhtml(content['body']['view'].get('value'))
        data.append(pgdata)            
   return data

# Pages to extract from
with open(r'C:\\Users\\Stacy\\Documents\\pages.txt') as pagesf:
     pagesl = pagesf.read()
pages = pagesl.split(",\n")        
print(pages)

# Preparing data frame and exporting to Excel
textdata = list()
for page in pages:
    print('Handing:', page)
    textdata.extend(get_data(page))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    textdata, 
    columns = ['text']
)

df.to_excel('page_data{}.xlsx'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H-%M")))
```

I want to collect the text from

```
 "value": "<p>Some text</p>",
```

into data and store all that in a dictionary. However, I see that content contains  data type and not  data, so I can't reference to 'body' as to a key, because it's not a key.

Please help me retrieve page data from 'value'. What would be the right way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I have come to:

```py
def get_words(page_id):
    comments = []
    r = s.get(
      '{}content/{}'.format(WIKI, page_id),
        params = dict(
           expand='body.view'
           )      
        )
    for cmnt in r: # No valid json, so we scan the result
        comments.append(cmnt) # Collect all strings into a list
        bytes = [] #Results are encoded, store decoded data in a list
        for byte in comments:
            byted = byte.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') #Decode as UTF-8 and ignore errors
            bytes.append(byted)
    bytesstr = "".join(bytes) # List contains split strings, join them together into a single line
    parsed = json.loads(bytesstr); # Convert the line into a valid JSON object
    pgdata =  dict() # Preparing dictionary to store extracted text
    pgdata['value'] = parsed['body']['view'].get('value') # Retrieving text from the page
    pgdatac = cleanhtml(pgdata['value']) # Removing HTML tags
    counts = len(re.findall(r'\w+', pgdatac)) # Extra line to calculate words on a page
    print(counts)
```